# How to set default parameter route variable in laravel?

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5

This is my route and I get a status variable but I want to set it up so that that if the status does not come then it must has a default parameter.

```
Route::get('/list/{status?}', [
    'as' => 'entegra.gg.p.list',
    'uses' => 'ggController@ggList'
]);
```

I want to set the default parameter for status variable. How can I do that ?

I set the parameter like this but I need to set up a default parameter:

```
<li><a href="{{ route('entegra.gg.p.list', ['status' => 'A']) }}">@lang('gg\index.sales.A')</a></li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set that in your method.

```
public function ggList($status = "default") {
    // do your magic...
}
```

If anything comes from the url, it will be overwritten.